# Error in eclipse but the page works

Tags: eclipse, jsp

when i write this line in my jsp page it works fin when i load the page.

```
<fmt:parseNumber var="leftDays"
    value="${( ao.dateOuverturePlis.getTime() - now.getTime() ) / (1000*60*60*24) }" 
 integerOnly="true" />
```

but eclipse show me there is a error with red icon

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, 
     column 31. 
Was expecting one of: 
    "." ... 
    ">" ... 
    "gt" ... 
    ...

    - EL Syntax Error
```

so how can i just get away this red error icon ?

Answer (score 1):

It works finnaly we change it `.getTime()` by `.time`  like that

```
<fmt:parseNumber var="leftDays"
    value="${( ao.dateOuverturePlis.time - now.time  ) / (1000*60*60*24) }" 
 integerOnly="true" />
```